# Hue not loading in browser

Tags: hadoop

I have a Hue installation on my local machine and the browser loads it very well in the browser when I give the URL

```
10.20.30.40:8888
```

in my browser.

When i do the same for a remote machine  (I have root and hdfs permissions to )with Hue installed, my browser does not load Hue it keeps on processing and waiting (10 - 12 mins).

```
11.22.33.44:8888
```

I can modify the Hue config files on the remote machine. Please tell me what needs to be done to set this right.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but fixed it by redirecting from port 80 to the other port instead. I'm not sure exactly what makes it not want to connect to other ports but for some reason I got it to work like that.

for http:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8888
```

If that doesn't work try searching for a way to redirect the port that works on your system.